# How to change value by clicking radio buttons

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am making a website in Adobe Dreamweaver with php. In the site there’s a 3 buttons for selecting payment method that will act as the continue button. What I want is when the user checks a radio buttons (I agree button), it will be add with that amount and display with previous amount.. there is three buttons which has the corresponding values(amount in pounds)..

plz check my website http://www.spsmobile.co.uk in this linkgo to mobile phone unlocking and after add the cart click make payment it will go to next page there is a delivery mail details.. for that delivery mail details only am asking..

plz give some idea or code.. i tried but i can't get the result

Comment: You're going to get much better results if you post pieces of relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

I dove into your code and found something like the following (simplified):

HTML:

```
<input id="radio-1" type="radio" name="rmr" value="1">
<label for="radio-1">£3</label>
<input id="radio-2" type="radio" name="rmr" value="2">
<label for="radio-2">£5.5</label>
<input id="radio-3" type="radio" name="rmr" value="4">
<label for="radio-3">£10</label>

<div class="total-text" style="font-size:36px">£10</div>
```

(`id`s added just so I could add labels)

With that in mind, you're going to want to do something like this:

```
var total = parseInt($("div.total-text").text().substring(1), 10);

$("input[name='rmr']").bind('change', function() {
    var amount = 0;
    switch (this.value) {
    case "1":
        amount = 3;
        break;
    case "2":
        amount = 5.5;
        break;
    case "4":
        amount = 10;
        break;
    }

    $("div.total-text").text("£" + (total + amount));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/LvvmV/

What's going on here:

- A `change` event handler is being bound to every radio button in the `rmr` group.
- When the user's selection changes, we're updating the text inside the `div` with class `total-text` with an amount based on the original total (see `var total` above) and the `value` of the radio button that was clicked.

Comment: sir That was a great article ...i have the problem with this <div class="total-text" style="font-size:36px">£10</div> my amount did nopt updated prop[erly what should i do for it start works..

Comment: any one can tell me what shoul i do <div class="total-text" style="font-size:36px">£10</div>   i have the problem with this code